# How can one obtain a classical solution of the initial value problem from distribution theory?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $a\neq 0$, if one assume $u$ is a solution of the following differential equation on $(0,\infty)$, $$au'+b u=0.$$
Then define $$v(x)= \begin{cases}u(x) & x >0 \\ u(-x) & x <0 \end{cases}$$ and
$$w(x)= \begin{cases}u(x) & x >0 \\ -u(-x) & x <0 \end{cases}.$$
We can get  the distribution equation $aV'(v)+bV(v)=0$ and $aW'(w)+bW(w)=0.$

My question is : How one can obtain a classical solution of the initial value problem from the distribution theory? e.g.$$au'+b u=0,x>0; u(0)=\alpha.$$

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to do here. Why do you introduce $v$ and $w$ when you anyway only are interested in $u(x)$ for $x>0$? On that domain $v\equiv w \equiv u$. Why can't you just solve the ODE directly and get the solution ($u(x) = \alpha e^{-x/a}$) the usual way?

Comment: I mean if we know the distribution solution how we get the classical solution with inital. Because we can define different  distribution equation from one usual equation